Humourous television series. An arrogant man seems to be giving a blow by blow account of a dangerous battle. He was describing a game of Risk
Two men are on a spaceship. One is arrogant and a windbag. He is telling a long and detailed story that seems to be about a dangerous battle in which he fought.
The other man loses his patience and says nobody wants to hear once again all about how you once beat your teacher at Risk!

This comes from the episode Meltdown of the British comedy sci fi series Red Dwarf.

RIMMER: So there we were at 2:30 in the morning; I was beginning to wish I had never come to cadet training school. To the south lay water - there was no way we could cross that. To the east and west two armies squeezed us in a pincer. The only way was north; I had to go for it and pray the Gods were smiling on me. I picked up the dice and threw two sixes. Caldecott couldn't believe it. My go again; another two sixes!

[...]

LISTER: No one wants to know some stupid story about how you beat your
Cadet School Training Officer at 'Risk'.


Ah yes, where later in the episode, Rimmer has his cohorts charge over the minefield under cover of daylight.

As soon as Risk was mentioned, I knew it would be Arnold J. Rimmer! (BSC, SSC)

Arrogant windbag on a spaceship was an even earlier hint...

Bronze Swimming Certificate. Silver Swimming Certificate

Later in the episode. KRYTEN: In the normal course of things it would take Starbug several billion years to reach it. LISTER: It wouldn't be so bad -- Rimmer could finish his Risk story.

A weird choice of game. If you know what you're doing, there really isn't much skill to Risk. Like a more complicated tic-tac-toe.

That’s the joke.

@Astrid_Redfern I have earned both a Bronze Swimming Certificate and a Bachelor of Science. I would value the first far more highly than the second if I were drowning. Rimmer ,as I'm sure you know, despite having his BSC cannot swim.

@JudithJones Indeed. Almost as if it's a clue, and there's a message hidden in the microdot over the 'i'.

Brings back many fond memories
